# Mockk verify wasNot called failed

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk, kotest

I have a question regarding `mockk`.

When using MockK's `wasNot called` to check that `ClassA` is called, there is a problem that the test fails if it is called in another test even if `ClassA` is not called in the current test.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
class ClassA {
  fun method(): Int = 1
}

class ClassB(val classA: ClassA, var call: Boolean = true) {
  fun method(): Int = if(call) classA.method() else 0
}


class MyTest: FreeSpec({
  "Test" - {
    val mockClassA = mockk<ClassA>()
    val sut = ClassB(mockClassA)

    "methodA called" - {
      every { mockClassA.method() } returns 1

      sut.method()

      verify { mockClassA.method() }
    }

    "methodA not called" - {
      every { mockClassA.method() } returns 1
      sut.call = false

      sut.method()

      verify { mockClassA wasNot called } // failed here
    }
  }
})
```

**Error message:**

```
Verification failed: ClassA(#1) should not be called:
```

Comment: Both tests identical, but with opposite names and  expectations!? :) Probably you want a new `sut`!?

Comment: Because your `mockClassA` is the same instance for both tests, so `mockk` records the calls. Usually the instatiation a mock is during some sort of `@Before`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how you can bypass that behavior.

#### Local mock

One way would be to just not reuse your mock, but instead create a new one, and and a new `sut` for each test. If this would lead to a lot of duplicated code, you can just write helper functions for the setup.

#### IsolationMode

You can define different [Isolation Modes](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/isolation-mode.html) for your Kotest test. The default one is `SingleInstance` which means that there is one single spec instantiated when running the tests in your test class.

When you change this to `InstancePerLeaf`, then for every test leaf in your spec, a new spec instance is created. You can define that at different locations, for instance it the global `ProjectConfig`:

```kotlin
class ProjectConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
    override val isolationMode = IsolationMode.InstancePerLeaf
}
```

or locally for your test like this:

```kotlin
class MyTest : FreeSpec({
    isolationMode = IsolationMode.InstancePerLeaf
    "Test" - {
...
```

#### Clear mock

You can clear the internal state of each mock with `clearMocks`, or alternatively for all mocks with `clearAllMocks`. When you do this after each test, then the verification does not fail due to calls in earlier tests.

You can call it like this:

```kotlin
        "methodA called" - {
            every { mockClassA.method() } returns 1

            sut.method()

            verify { mockClassA.method() }
            clearMocks(mockClassA)
        }
```

or for all tests like this:

```kotlin
        afterAny {
            clearMocks(mockClassA)
        }
        "methodA called" - {
...
```